# Charging credit card via Magento admin new order using Authorize.Net

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, payment, authorize.net

Some of our customers provide their credit card information via phone or email to buy merchandises. Items are expensive and the way to avoid fraud transactions, we use Signifyd.com to protect our sales.

We have Virtual Terminals to charge customers but by this way, they will not check for any fraud possibilities. (We are using Athorized.net as the merchant account) By adding a new order in Magento admin panel, we have an option to fill the credit card information in payment section.

After entering credit card information, it gets error while saving the order (Gateway error: This transaction cannot be accepted)This error is generated when your Authorize.Net account is in Password-Required Mode and you are not sending a valid Transaction Key.

[image: creen shot for payment option in admin new order]

Is there any way to charge the card through admin panel by making a new order? .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A471&actp=LIST

> When your account is placed in Password-Required Mode, the payment
>   gateway requires a Transaction Key or fingerprint hash for each
>   transaction submitted.
>
> You should turn Password-Required Mode ON if you use Advanced
>   Integration Method (AIM), Server Integration Method (SIM), or the
>   Virtual Terminal and Upload Transaction File features.
>
> You should turn Password-Required Mode OFF if you use WebLink. All
>   WebLink transactions submitted with a password will be rejected.
>
> Note: If you submit a Transaction Key or fingerprint hash with your
>   transaction requests, we will attempt to validate it even if
>   Password-Required Mode is disabled.

Try disabling 'Password-Required Mode OFF' and check your Authorize.Net setting in system config

Comment: I disabled 'Password-Required Mode' and then tried to make an order in admin panel and still the same issue.

Comment: Did you check your Authorize.Net config in magento to make sure they are valid?

Comment: Yes, because I'm able to place orders in frontend

Comment: Are you running single or multi-store?

Comment: I'm using single store

Comment: Any suggestions?